# Angularjs - Execute function javascript when load my template component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the index.html file of my SPA I have declared a javascript function:

```
<script>
function getData() {
//get data
}
</script>
```

In turn from an HTML template of an Angular component, I need to access that javascript function when that component is loaded (onload), but I must to do it from the html template, I can not do it from the typescript controller.

For example, if I want to access a javascript function of my index.html with an "onclick" event from my html template, it works perfectly, but I do not know how to do it, to execute the javascript function as soon as it load the page.

```
<div id="data_main" onclick="getData();">Get Data</div> <!--working ok-->
```

With directive ng-init not working, because I can't to pass a javascript function.

```
<div id="data_main" ng-init="getData();">Get Data</div> <!--not working ok-->
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: There is no particular moment when the component can be considered 'loaded' because it may contain asynchronous actions. This is totally specific to your case. *I can not do it from the typescript controller* - a proper approach is to move this logic to controller. You can't access globals from templates, also this smells very bad,

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that the function I have to called, only working ok if do defined from html file because are external functions of thirds and from controller the code typescript the not compile correctly.

Comment: This is likely specific to the way you build your app and surely there's a way to make it compile properly. An ugly workaround for asynchronous initialization is to put ready event listener `$(() =>{...})` or even window load event listener inside getData.

Answer (score 0):

The following line

```
<div id="data_main" ng-init="getData();">Get Data</div>
```

requires `getData()` to be present in the attached `$scope`. You need to assign the function to the scope first to use it in the template.

In your controller, inject `$window` and assign the function to `$scope` like this:

```
angular.module('yourMod', [])
  .controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.getData = $window.getData;
  });
```

Now you can use it as usual in the template:

```
<div ng-controller="yourCtrl">
  <div id="data_main" ng-init="getData();">Get Data</div>
</div>
```